# How to generate multiple check boxes in symfony2 form

Tags: php, symfony

I want to display checkboxes from a pre-defined array in my Symfony form. User should be able to select more than one but I am not able to do it.

This is my code:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $roles = array('role1', 'role2', 'role3');
    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('roles', 'checkbox', $roles)
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

See the [`choice` type reference](http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/forms/types/choice.html).

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $roles = ['role1', 'role2', 'role3'];

    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('roles', 'choice', [
            'choices' => $roles,
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => true
        ])
    ;
}
```

Comment: Nice example but i want to know how can you specify the default selected role? the data is coming from DB and then you need to display the selected value. I know that is a 4 years old question / answer but i am interested

Answer (score 6):

You can use a `choice` field instead:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{        
    $roles = array("role1","role2","role3");
    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('roles', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => $roles,
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => true,
        ))    
    ;
}
```

Look at the documentation to know how you can have a checkbox, a select, or radio buttons with this field type: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#forms-reference-choice-tags